# If $G$ is finitely generated and $G/N$ is finitely presented , then $N$ is normal closure of finite set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, universal-property

> Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a finitely presented .Then show that $N$ is a normal closure of some finite set of $G$.

---

[My attempt]

Let $\pi : G \to G/N$ be a natural quotient map.

Since $G/N$ is a finitely presented, there exist a exact sequence of group
$$ 1  \; \to \; \langle R\rangle \; \to \; F(S) \; \stackrel{f}{\to} \; G/N \; \to \; 1 $$
where, $F(S)$ is free group on $S$ and $R$ is a relation set. ($F$, $S$ are finite)
($\langle \cdot\rangle$: normal closure notation)

Since $F(S)$ is free, we construct map $\phi: F(S) \to G $ such that $f=\pi \; \circ \; \phi$.

Therefore, we obtain $\phi(R) \subset \ker\pi = N$ so $\langle \phi(R)\rangle \;\subseteq N$.

I'm stuck here.

How can I prove that $ N \subseteq \; \langle \phi(R)\rangle $ ?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's no escaping the result, which I learned from the paper

> B. H. Neumann, Some remarks on infinite groups, J. London Math. Soc. **12** (1937),
> 120–127,

but which I understand is a basic fact in universal algebra, that

> if a group is finitely presented with respect to a particular finite set of generators, then it is so with respect to any finite set of generators.

Suppose $G$ is generated by the finite set $S$. Let $F$ be the free group on $S$. Then we have natural surjective morphisms
$$
F \overset{f}{\to} G \overset{\pi}{\to} G/N.
$$
Let $K$ the kernel of the composite map. By the above result, there is a finite subset $T$ of $F$ such that $K$ is the normal closure in $F$ of $T$. Now the image of $K$ under $f$ is $N$, so $N$ is the normal closure in $G$ of the finite set $f(T)$ .

---

**Addendum** Contrary to my expectations, you can indeed avoid the result I quoted, see Derek Holt's comment below.

Comment: If you really wanted to avoid the result you are using, then you could start with a set $S \subseteq G$ that generates $G$ modulo $N$ for which there is a finite presentation $\langle S \mid R \rangle$ of $G/N$, and then, since $G$ is finitely generated, we can adjoin a finite set $T$ of elements of $N$ such that $G = \langle S \cup T \rangle$, and now we can use the finite presentation $\langle S \cup T \mid R \cup T \rangle$ of $G/N$.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti , Thank you , may I ask you something? I don't understand the statement "if a group is finitely presented with respect to a particular finite set of generators, then it is so with respect to any finite set of generators."

That is, if $G=<a,b,c,d> $ generator, then any subset (ex. $\{ a, c\} $) is also generate $G=<a,c>$?

Comment: so, I don't understand how to derive $K$ is the normal closure in $F$ of $T$.. Sorry , I'm not familiar with this language.

Comment: @hew, to your first question, this means that if the group $H$ is finitely presented, and $E$ is a free group on a finite set such that there is a surjective homomorphism $f : E \to H$, then the kernel of $f$ is the normal closure of a finite set. This should also answer your second question,

Comment: @hew, no, the definition of *finitely presented* tells you that *there exist* such an $E$ and $f$. I am claiming that for *any* fg free group $E$ and any surjective homomorphism $f$ etc etc

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you! Then, in last part , how can I derive "Now the image of $K$ under$ f $ is $N$" ? I know $f(K) \subseteq N$ ,but i'm stuck here for other direction.

Comment: @DerekHolt , Thank you, now I understand your comment  $G=<S \cup T>$ but I don't know how to conclude this problem ,using this. It is the same question that how can I prove that $N \subseteq f(K)$

Comment: The important point is that the map $f$ chosen by Andreas Caranti is surjective. So, for $n \in N$, there exists $g \in F$ with $f(g) = n$, and then $a \in \ker( \pi \circ f)$, so $g \in K$.