# What is a finitely generated G-operator group?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated

[I'm self-studying group theory after many, many years away, using Derek Robinson's book.]

Robinson in Ex 2.2.8 says:

> Let G be a finitely presented group and let N be a normal subgroup which is *finitely generated as a G-operator group.*  Prove that G/N is finitely presented.

I think I understand all the words like "G-operator" and "finitely generated," but I don't know what they mean combined (as emphasised in this sentence.)

[Note: I'm not asking for a solution to the problem (yet!) but just to know what it means.]

Comment: Why doesn't it just mean both properties combined? Finitely generated, *and* $G$-operator group? By the way, your post from [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973952/if-g-is-finitely-generated-and-g-n-is-finitely-presented-then-n-is-norma) is related (but different, yes).

Comment: thanks for the link -- I may come back to that later.  But isn't "N is a G-operator group" true for any N?  Can't I just take every endomorphism to be the identity?  In that case, it's equivalent to just "N is finitely generated"?  I'm sure I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Dietrich's guess in the comments is correct (the word "as" is relevant). My guess is that "finitely generated as a $G$-operator group" means that there exists a finite subset $S$ of $N$ such that every element of $N$ can be obtained from this subset by repeated multiplication *and* the action of $G$ (by conjugation). Equivalently, $N$ is generated (as a group) by $\cup_{g \in G} gSg^{-1}$.

Note that the exercise is much easier if you just assume that $N$ is finitely generated but then there's no need to mention the concept of a $G$-operator group at all.

Comment: Thanks!  I will think about your answer.  Meanwhile, why is it necessary to assume the operation is conjugation?

Comment: @Andrew: that is, from context, the intended operation of $G$ on $N$ ($N$ is a normal subgroup and all).

Comment: Thank you @Qiaochu Yuan - this all works out, I think l solved the problem using this definition.  So I've accepted it.